# How to output a line containing a match AND the line before?

Tags: windows, cmd

> Tool zur Imageverwaltung für die Bereitstellung
>   Version: 10.0.17763.1
>   Abbildversion: 10.0.17763.253
>   Funktionsliste:
>   Funktionsidentität : Browser.InternetExplorer~~~~0.0.11.0
>   Status : Nicht vorhanden
>   Funktionsidentität : Hello.Face.17658~~~~0.0.1.0
>   Status : Installiert
>   Funktionsidentität : Hello.Face.Migration.17658~~~~0.0.1.0
>   Status : Installiert
>   Funktionsidentität : Language.Basic~~~af-ZA~0.0.1.0
>   Status : Nicht vorhanden

I want to output the lines where the next line contains `Status: Installiert`.

I know how to find the lines containing the string `Installiert`, but don't know how to include the whole line before the match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command line written into a batch file can be used for this task:

```
@for /F "usebackq delims= eol=" %%I in ("TextFile.txt") do @for /F "tokens=2 eol= delims=: " %%J in ("%%~I") do @if "%%~J" == "Installiert" (call echo(%%Line%%) else set "Line=%%I"
```

The outer **FOR** interprets `"` as end of line character. So lines starting with `"` would be ignored by outer **FOR**.

The inner **FOR** interprets a space character as end of line character which does not matter here because the space character is also a delimiter. The line splitting is done first by **FOR** resulting in removing all spaces and colons from beginning of line and so space as end of line character is no problem here.

Thanks goes to [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl) for these additional information on how the two **FOR** above with the specified options process the lines in specified text file.

Better would be:

```
@for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ("TextFile.txt") do @for /F "tokens=2 delims=: eol=" %%J in ("%%~I") do @if "%%~J" == " Installiert" (call echo(%%Line%%) else set "Line=%%I"
```

The outer **FOR** is run with an empty list of string delimiters and no end of line character. The inner **FOR** is run also with no end of line character, but with just colon as string delimiter which is the reason for the space character at beginning of the string to compare.

Both command lines output on execution with file `TextFile.txt` in current directory containing the posted lines:

```
Funktionsidentität : Hello.Face.17658~~~~0.0.1.0
Funktionsidentität : Hello.Face.Migration.17658~~~~0.0.1.0
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`

Comment: This would define a `"` as the `eol` character for the outer `for /F` loop and a _space_ for the inner one (although for the latter it is no problem as the _space_ is also a delimiter, which has got a higher priority)...